# Why are am i getting out of memory error when i use codenameone result processor?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use the result processor to extract information from a HashMap like so
        Result result = Result.fromContent(co);
    System.out.println(co.toString());
    System.out.println(result.get("//propertyType[text()='Image'/..").toString());

When I run, I get this output. The out of memory error does not come immediately after and there is really no other code that i am running.

```
{
```

"Picture": {
    "propertyName": "Picture",
    "propertyType": "Image",
    "propertyValue": "/var/folders/_j/xsgymcmd1lsc5zqtg65ctlsm0000gn/T/temp7922678673908500238s.png"
  },
  "DocumentType": {
    "propertyName": "DocumentType",
    "propertyType": "Text",
    "propertyValue": "Accident"
  }
}
{Picture={propertyName=Picture, propertyType=Image, propertyValue=/var/folders/_j/xsgymcmd1lsc5zqtg65ctlsm0000gn/T/temp7922678673908500238s.png}, DocumentType={propertyName=DocumentType, propertyType=Text, propertyValue=Accident}}

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:587)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:332)
    at com.codename1.processing.ResultTokenizer.getPredicate(ResultTokenizer.java:124)
    at com.codename1.processing.ResultTokenizer.next(ResultTokenizer.java:137)
    at com.codename1.processing.ResultTokenizer.tokenize(ResultTokenizer.java:77)
    at com.codename1.processing.Result._internalGetAsArray(Result.java:860)
    at com.codename1.processing.Result._internalGet(Result.java:556)
    at com.codename1.processing.Result.get(Result.java:540)
    at com.ixzdore.icomplain.ComplainManager.saveComplainObject(ComplainManager.java:23)
    at userclasses.StateMachine.onEditorSave(StateMachine.java:299)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.processCommand(StateMachineBase.java:228)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.processCommandImpl(UIBuilder.java:1634)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.access$100(UIBuilder.java:85)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder$FormListener.actionPerformed(UIBuilder.java:2757)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:345)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.actionCommandImpl(Form.java:1305)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.dispatchCommand(Form.java:1271)
    at com.codename1.ui.SideMenuBar$CommandWrapper$ShowWaiter.run(SideMenuBar.java:1381)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1075)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1019)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:925)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

Answer (score 0):

An out of memory often indicates recursion. Does your map contain a reference to itself or to one of its children?

In that case the code would keep digging deeper and deep and would end up in a loop. I suggest stopping with a debugger breakpoint and inspect the children of the map to see that none of them recurse infinitely.

Comment: I replaced the map with a json string and get same result. definitely no recursing.

Comment: I misread the stack, its due to the get call. I'm guessing something in the expression language isn't working here but I'm not sure what. I don't use that functionality often and just traverse the Map instead.

Comment: Oh well. Result seems not to work very well. I will traverse the map too.